# Find the missing value for "main"

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

```
coal    60 

mine    63 

code    39 

lame    41 

gain    23 

gala    22 

main    ?
```

Find the missing value for "main"?

> Hint: there are hidden abbreviations in the words!

Comment: case matters and there's a reason every word has two vowels

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My answer:

> main = 6 + 19 = 25

Reasoning:

> Each word is composed of two 2-letter US state abbreviations. The number is the sum of the order in which the states were admitted to the United States. For example, COAL = Colorado + Alabama = 38 + 22 = 60. Here's the full list:
> coal = Colorado + Alabama = 38 + 22= 60
> mine = Michigan + Nebraska = 26 + 37 = 63
> code = Colorado + Deleware = 38 + 1 = 39
> lame = Louisiana + Maine = 18 + 23 = 41
> gain = Georgia + Indiana = 4 + 19 = 23
> gala = Georgia + Louisiana = 4 + 18 = 22
> main = Massachusetts + Indiana = 6 + 19 = 25

Comment: I think I made it too hard by not giving the hint, glad it is solved :) Thanks.

Comment: I think it would have gotten solved without the hint... eventually. But it might have taken a while longer. The hint did help quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

So I might be completely off on this, but I think the answer is:

> main=20

My Solution:

> coal - code=al - de (= 21)
> al - de - lame =  - made (= - 20)
>  - mine + made = ad - in (= - 43)
> ad - in + gain = adgd (= - 21)
> adga - gala = d - l (= - 43)
> d - l + coal = coad (= 17)
> code - code = a - e (= - 22)
> a - e + lame = mala (= 19)
> mala - gala = m - g (= - 3)
> m - g + gain = main (= 20)

Comment: sorry, good try but it is not like this. it is more like about abbreviations given in the question.